# How to enable hard float when cross compiling FFTW for Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, cross-compiling

I'm trying to compile a third party library ([FFTW](http://www.fftw.org/)) for Android which is running on an ARM device. The library includes a benchmark tool which I want to run on my device. Following Google's instructions (https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) on how to configure for hard float with NDK r9d I'm using the following flags:

```
NDK_ROOT="/opt/android/ndk"
TOOLCHAIN="$NDK_ROOT/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/"

export SYS_ROOT="$NDK_ROOT/platforms/android-18/arch-arm"
export CC="$TOOLCHAIN/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=$SYS_ROOT"
export LD="$TOOLCHAIN/arm-linux-androideabi-ld"
export AR="$TOOLCHAIN/arm-linux-androideabi-ar"
export NM="$TOOLCHAIN/arm-linux-androideabi-nm"
export RANLIB="$TOOLCHAIN/arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib"
export STRIP="$TOOLCHAIN/arm-linux-androideabi-strip"

export CFLAGS="-mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mhard-float -D_NDK_MATH_NO_SOFTFP=1"
export LDFLAGS="-Wl,-lm_hard -Wl,--no-warn-mismatch"


./configure \
--host=arm-linux-androideabi \
--disable-fortran \
--disable-shared \
--enable-static \
--enable-threads \
--with-combined-threads \
--enable-single \
--prefix=$INSTALL_DIR
```

With this configuration the benchmark is performing extremely poor. To me it looks like the library is compiled with softfloat or a soft float libm is linked.

How can I configure the library to use hard float? Am I missing an essential step?

I know that the FPU on my device works because I have a second device running ArchLinux on which the library and benchmark perform as expected, i.e. 600% faster than on Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue. There were three points missing.

1. Firstly I was missing compiler optimization. Turning on -O2 significantly improved performance. So the CFLAGS are

   ```
   CFLAGS="-O2 -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mhard-float -D_NDK_MATH_NO_SOFTFP=1"
   ```
2. The second point is library and platform speficic. This post ([Application hang after call nested function with Android NDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11510856/application-hang-after-call-nested-function-with-android-ndk)) delivers the answer. In short add

   ```
   --with-slow-timer
   ```
3. As @andrewsieh said it is necessary to edit *configure* so that libm is not always linked before libm_hard.a

Answer (score 1):

In order to link hard-float version of math functions in libm_hard.a, you need to put `-lm_hard` after all objects files but before `-lm`, which is Android's libc.so compiled in soft-float.  `LDFLAGS="-Wl,-lm_hard"` doesn't work in FFTW because it's put before all object files.  `LIBS="-lm_hard"` may work, but configure sets `LIBS="-lm $LIBS"` at the end, which puts `-lm` in front of `-lm_hard`.  You can remove that line in configure to workaround, although a better fix is to allow customization of system math lib, or filter out `-lm` in ltmain.sh if `-lm_hard` is present for `$host arm-*linux-android`.

Comment: Yes I figured that out and as you said worked around be editing _configure_